# How do I change the borderColor of just one Textinput with onFocus in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, textinput

I'm currently attempting to change the borderColor of a single Textinput element, using the prop onFocus.  I'm using an array that contains two sets of styles, the first one "styles.textInput" should be the first one that is loaded.  The second should only load when toggle is true and then it should load the second style which is "styles.textInputAlt"

Right now, the borderColor of BOTH textInputs are changing.  How do I make sure that the only textInput that gets changes is the one that's currently onFocus?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import  {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View,

} from 'react-native';

export default class Highlight extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            toggle: false,
        }
    }

    hasFocus(){
        this.setState({
            toggle: !this.state.toggle
        })
    }

    lostFocus(){
        this.setState({
            toggle:this.state.toggle,
        })

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput 
                    style={[styles.textInput, this.state.toggle && styles.textInputAlt]}
                    onFocus={()=>this.hasFocus()}  
                    onBlur={()=>this.lostFocus()}
                    /> 

                <TextInput
                    style={[styles.textInput, this.state.toggle && styles.textInputAlt]}
                    onFocus={()=>this.hasFocus()}
                    onBlur={()=>this.lostFocus()}

                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',

  },
  textInput: {
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 2.0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    height: 40,
    marginLeft: 60,
    marginRight: 60,
    marginBottom: 30,
    padding: 2,
  },
  textInputAlt: {
    borderColor: '#e71636',
  },
  button: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#48bbec',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginLeft: 60,
    marginRight: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 22,
    color: '#FFF',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

an easy way to solve your situation is to use parameters, here's a very basic example:

```
//Methods
handlerFocus = (input) => {
    this.setState({
        [input]:true
     });
};

handlerBlur = (input) => {
    this.setState({
        [input]:false
    });
};

// In render method         
<TextInput
    style= {[
        styles.textInput,
        this.state.nameInputOneFocus?styles.textInputFocus:''
    ]}
    onFocus = {() => this.handlerFocus('nameInputOneFocus')}
    onBlur = {() => this.handlerBlur('nameInputOneFocus')}
/>

<TextInput
    style= {[
        styles.textInput,
        this.state.nameInputTwoFocus?styles.textInputFocus:''
    ]}
    onFocus = {() => this.handlerFocus('nameInputTwoFocus')}
    onBlur = {() => this.handlerBlur('nameInputTwoFocus')}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, while correct, has one problem. You are tracking whether any text input is focused or not, however you should be tracking `this.state.toggle` for each text input seperately (toggle1 and toggle2, if you will). Because of this, when you focus anything your application updates state and since both text inputs decide their color based on `this.state.toggle` they both change their color.

Comment: I'm not sure how to track this.state.toggle inside the textInput.  Should I do it via an IF statement?(that doesn't seem likely).  Or do it within the hasFocus method?

Comment: Add a new variable to state. In your hasFocus and lostFocus methods, call them as ```() => this.hasFocus('first')``` and in those methods create an if to toggle new or old toggle variable. Lastly, in style one of your textinputs should look at this.state.toggle and the other to the new variable there.

Comment: I added a new state called toggleCheck.  Should i set it to 'first'.  Sorry, I'm still confused about this